# coloring and adding buttons to annotations in a mutable array in iOS

Tags: ios, mkannotation

I am coding an application that uses a mapView in iOS.
I am trying to color the annotations in the mutable array to purple and to add a disclosure button to each pin .
The reason that I am using a mutable array is that I am going to retrieve many places from a DB to view each place on the map with a pin.

My code is :

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


//code of map

[mapMKMapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];

[mapMKMapView setZoomEnabled:YES];

[mapMKMapView setScrollEnabled:YES];


MKCoordinateRegion newRegion = { {0.0, 0.0},{0.0, 0.0}};

newRegion.center.latitude = 12.968427;

newRegion.center.longitude = 44.997704;

newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.004731;

newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.006952;

[self.mapMKMapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];



//multiple annotations

NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];

CLLocationCoordinate2D loc;

annotationClass *myAnn;



//1st annotation

myAnn = [[annotationClass alloc] init];

loc.latitude = 12.968427;

loc.longitude = 44.997704;

myAnn.coordinate = loc;

myAnn.title = @"Nakheel2";

myAnn.subtitle = @"This Al-Nakheel 2 stage";

[locations addObject:myAnn];



//2nd annotaion

myAnn = [[annotationClass alloc] init];

loc.latitude = 12.971532;

loc.longitude = 44.998015;

myAnn.coordinate = loc;

myAnn.title = @"Nakheel21";

myAnn.subtitle = @"This Al-Nakheel 2 stage Hi";

[locations addObject:myAnn];



[self.mapMKMapView addAnnotations:locations];

}


//******

-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)locations

{

MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:locations reuseIdentifier:@"current"];

MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;



UIButton *adverButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

[adverButton addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = adverButton;

MyPin.draggable = NO;

MyPin.highlighted = YES;

MyPin.animatesDrop  = TRUE;

MyPin.canShowCallout  = YES;



return MyPin;

}
```

Comment: ok what is your question?

Comment: my question is how to run the function of coloring pins?,, it is not working when I test the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `viewForAnnotation` delegate method will be called by the map view automatically (you don't explicitly "run" it).

The most likely reason the map view is not calling it is that the map view's `delegate` is not set.

In the storyboard or xib, make sure the map view's `delegate` outlet is connected to the view controller (right-click or ctrl-click the map view and connect the delegate outlet to the view controller).

Or, you can add this line in the code in `viewDidLoad` before the `setMapType`:

```
//code of map
mapMKMapView.delegate = self;                 // <-- add this line
[mapMKMapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
```

An unrelated point:

Instead of using a custom action method for the button, I suggest using the map view's own `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method.  In that method, you'll get direct access to the annotation object that was tapped (via `view.annotation`).  Remove the `addTarget` and the `button:` method if you decide to use the delegate method.